# Upload .exe file in WordPress website

Tags: wordpress

I need to upload .exe file in my wordpress website. I have already added define('ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS', true); in my wp-config.php file but still showing the same error. Please help.
Thanks

Comment: Whatever problem you're trying to solve by allowing EXE uploads, there is likely a safer/better way to do it.

Comment: Try this answer : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/75127/106350

Comment: @user1751825 Imagine I want to write a program that downloads an installer from my WP website.

Comment: @EmilMocan my use case exactly- way easier than setting up a separate server- executable downloads are a common practice across the web

Comment: I would actually like to add code formatting, but trying to edit it tells me "Title cannot contain "Upload .exe file in WordPress website".

Please provide a title that summarizes your question. For assistance, see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" - so that's what I recommend too

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks for you comment, below code solved my issue,

```
function enable_extended_upload ( $mime_types =array() ) {

   // The MIME types listed here will be allowed in the media library.
   // You can add as many MIME types as you want.
   $mime_types['exe']  = 'application/exe'; 

   return $mime_types;
} 
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'enable_extended_upload');
```

Comment: added this to my functions.php, worked great w/ wordpress 5.2

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same issue and [the current answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41251700/3948974) no longer works for me.

The following works for me in wordpress 5.7.2 (tested using the basic file uploader):

Create a new `.php` file in the `wp-content/mu-plugins` directory, with the following content:

```
<?php

// specify a high priority so that the filter will run later
// there is a built in filter which will remove the entry for 'exe'
add_filter('upload_mimes', function($mimes) {
    // this mimetype has to match exactly what 
    // finfo_file() will return, see wp_check_filetype_and_ext()
    $mimes['exe'] = 'application/x-dosexec';
    return $mimes;
}, 10000);
```

Comment: I tried this but it gives a 403 response in the console in async-upload.php. What could it cause?

Comment: Have you tried using the basic file uploader (the old one)? Wordpress has two interfaces to upload files. So far, I have not tried to make this work for the more modern uploader.

Comment: Do you mean at /wp-admin/media-new.php ?

Comment: It turned out my server upload limit was only 64 MB